# Does 'affect' imply negative effect?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity

when I say A affects B, does it imply that A has a negative effect on B?

Comment: Related and Possible Duplicate:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16248/what-is-the-difference-between-affect-and-influence

Comment: Do note that psychiatrists and psychologists use the term "affect" as a noun to refer to the "mood" of a patient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

> Sunshine affects my mood.

That sentence is entirely neutral; it's impossible to say whether I feel better or worse in sunshine. One might assume that I enjoy it, or perhaps it exacerbates a skin condition. You can't tell.

Very often there is enough **context** to determine whether the effect of A on B is positive or negative...

> Sunshine affects my mood. I'm always smiling.
>   Sunshine affects my mood. I try to stay indoors.

...but the context is necessary. The initial sentence on its own is not enough.

Comment: So if I ask someone `What are the industries that are affected by Industry X?` It really means both positive and negative, right?

Comment: Without more context, yes. To take a poor example, "What are the industries that are affected by the American car industry?" -- there are part manufacturers upstream and dealerships downstream. But if the car industry is in decline, then bicycle manufacturers might be benefiting.

Comment: So to frame a question or statement which includes __affect__, we should also provide context.

Comment: @VivekTodi - "affect" does NOT connote either negative or positive result, affect merely indicates that something influenced or caused some response in another thing. the further details you provide will indicate or determine whether or not the affect is/was negative or positive.

Comment: Though AHDEL and RHK Webster's don't include the caveat, Collins gives _affect_  .1. to act upon or influence, esp in an adverse way. >> I must argue that this indicates there is a connotation of a negative effect in an uncontextualised statement (and OP's is certainly that). An unaccompanied 'You have to say the weather affected his chances' would most often be construed as 'in a deleterious way', although this may not necessarily be the intended meaning.

Comment: The answer is right on -- *"affect"* has no connotation. It's synonymous with "*impact*" or *"influence*".

Comment: @Martin Krzywinski You have a dictionary that lists connotations? If a major dictionary says 'especially in an adverse way' in a denotation, saying 'affect' doesn't even connote this is very ... er ... subjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It seems to me that it is the context and the expectations it sets up that drives the negative de-/connotation more than the word itself. In your example, most likely negative. In something like “The outcome of the next match will affect the odds given for the semi-finals”, though, the effect is implicitly neither positive nor negative (or both and), and in “A healthy diet significantly affects your energy levels”, it is clearly positive. “Your diet significantly affects your energy levels”, though? Would you assume _bad_ diet _lowers_? _Good_ diet _improves_? (N)either/both?

Comment: It's **always** expectations (influenced by the filter of one's past) that influence(!) connotations. But the context involved includes the listener's experiences as well as the (here obviously more influential) immediate verbal context. An unaccompanied 'You have to say the weather affected his chances' would most often be construed as 'in a deleterious way'. Mitigation is probably intended. An unexpected twist would be 'You have to say the weather affected his chances. All the professionals refused to race!' Here, 'improved' is the expected verb for the positive reading.

Answer (score 0):

It would be sensible to define your terms. Which sense of *imply* would you like us to guess you're using (imply 2. (Logic) to **suggest** or **involve as a necessary consequence** [Collins])?

...........................

The best ways to investigate this sort of claim do include looking in decent dictionaries.

Compare the first-given (and in a non-historical dictionary, this indicates frequency of this sense being the intended one) definitions for the transitive usage/s at [AHDEL, Collins and RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affect):

> **affect**
>
> .1. To have an influence on or effect a change in: Inflation affects the buying power of the dollar.  [AHDEL]
>
> .1. to act upon or influence, esp in an adverse way: damp affected the sparking plugs.[Collins]
>
> .1. to produce an effect or change in: Cold weather affected the crops.[RHK Webster's]

So there is at least a connotation of a negative (in the sense of adverse) effect. The Collins definition pushes this reasonably close to denotation, but it's probably justifiable to average these analyses to get a general picture.

This is doubtless compounded by the most usual sense of the homonym:

affect[2] 1. To put on a false show of; simulate [AHDEL]

This is not to say that these vibes will be picked up identically by all people, and certainly not in all contexts (The mass of a planet will obviously affect its gravity).

Comment: My personal impression is that 'affect' is generally used to convey a negative influence ... but that is probably more a question of usage rather than semantic!!

Comment: Surely usage and semantics are inseparable.

Comment: But your dictionary examples are not evidence that affect connotes negative - crops + cold = negative; damp + electricity = negative etc. The negatives are in the nature of the examples. Words can be misused, surely, and meaning is just as surely affected.

Comment: I will always have the Collins caveat 'esp in an adverse way' at the back of my mind (if not more prominent in my thoughts) whenever I encounter 'affect'. Yes, I will rule out the 'esp in an adverse way' **denotation** where I consider it unwarranted, but 'affect' connotes the negative flavour as long as at least I (and, from their question, OP) am alive and relatively compos mentis. It was mentioned in a previous question that a 'connotation' is attached to a single word / lexeme and needs only one person to pick up on it. Though Collins' 'esp in an adverse way' guarantees I'm not alone.

Comment: Subjective? Are you saying that Collins has got it wrong? They only report usages they find, so they must have found a fair number of them to mention 'especially in an adverse way'.

Comment: @Little Eva This issue is not just 'philosophical'. A major dictionary gives as its first definition for _affect_ 'to act upon or influence, esp in an adverse way'. To discount this is essentially to say that you (and we're all learning the language) know better than the editorial board analysing the corpus data at that dictionary. Or worse, that you refuse to listen to arguments not pointing the way you would like them to. And this is semantics, not grammar.

Comment: As Matt Gutting has said, "What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case a ... dictionary or some other such document)." People writing in saying 'But the way I use it is ...' is hardly as convincing as a dictionary's corpus data (67% of a carefully chosen sample of 5000 written and spoken examples were ...).

Comment: Right. I didn't offer a personal anecdote as an answer but as a comment and question to you.

Comment: @Little Eva '... VivekTodi - "affect" does NOT connote either negative or positive result[;] affect merely indicates that something influenced or caused some response in another thing' sounds very much like an answer to me, no matter where it appears. And it does not take into account dictionary material.

Comment: Sir, See my answer as reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my view is contrarian to the ones here.  Yes I do think 'affect' has a negative connotation.  To start with 'effect' is a noun and 'affect' is a verb.  Effect is usually qualified (with an adjective) to give a +ve or -ve connotation eg. Lack of regular sleep could have a detrimental effect on your studies.  'Sunshine affects my mood' is not a common usage like say 'gloomy weather affects my mood' and obviously it puts a -ve connotation.  While one can use say 'spur' to indicate a +ve effective - for eg, morning jog spurs me to start the day on a bright note.  At the same, for eg, A lengthy meeting or discussions affects my schedule - it can be read in only one way (-ve).  To summarize, I think effect has a neutral, if not +ve, ring to it while affect has a -ve ring to it.

Answer (score 0):

AFFECT does not connote either negative or positive result, "affect" merely indicates that something influenced or caused some response or change in another person/object/event. The further details you provide will "affect" or determine whether or not the import of your expression is understood as negative or positive.

What follows are the first 4 results I encountered on a keyword search of AFFECT (note: these definitions are *not* cherry-picked to support my position. I'm sure you will find just as many dictionaries that disagree with my contention.)

> **AFFECT** (*verb*): **1**. the conscious subjective aspect of feeling or emotion; **2**. affect, impact, bear upon, bear on, touch on, touch; (*verb*) have an effect upon. "Will the new rules affect me."; **3**. affect (*verb*): act physically on; have an effect upon. “the medicine affects my heart rate" **4**. Involve, affect, regard (*verb*) connect closely and often incriminatingly. "This new ruling affects your business"; **5**. feign, sham, pretend, affect, dissemble (*verb*): make believe with the intent** to deceive "He feigned that he was ill"; "He shammed a headache" **6**. affect, impress, move, strike (*verb*): have an emotional or cognitive impact upon “This child impressed me as unusually mature”; This behavior struck me as odd” **Definitions.net**
>
> **AFFECT** (*verb*): **1**. to act upon; to produce an effect or change upon; **2**. affect (*verb*): to influence or move, as the feelings or passions; to touch; **3**. affect (*verb*): to love; to regard with affection; **4**. affect (*verb*): to show a fondness for; to like to use or practice; to choose; hence, to frequent habitually; **5**. affect (*verb*): to dispose or incline; **6**. affect (*verb*): to aim at; to aspire; to covet; **7**. affect (*verb*): to tend to by affinity or disposition; **8**. affect (*verb*) to make a show of; to put on a pretense of; to feign; to affect ignorance; **9**. affect (*verb*): to assign; to appoint; **10**. affect (*noun*): affection; inclination; passion; feeling; disposition. **Webster Dictionary**
>
> **AFFECT** (*verb*): affect; 3rd person present: affects; past tense: affected; past participle: affected; gerund or present participle: affecting
>
> have an effect on; make a difference to. "the dampness began to affect my health" synonyms: have an effect on, influence, act on, work on, have an impact on, impact;
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=affect+define&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **AFFECT**
>
> **1**:obsolete : feeling, affection
>
> **2**: the conscious subjective aspect of an emotion considered apart from bodily changes; also: a set of observable manifestations of a subjectively experienced emotion (patients … showed perfectly normal reactions and affects—Oliver Sacks)
>
> [**Merriam-Webster**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect)

Comment: And yet Collins has '_affect_: 1. to act upon or influence, esp in an adverse way'.   And Macmillan even has the sense 'to cause physical damage to something ... Synonyms and related words
To damage or spoil something: damage, spoil, mark, harm, stain, mar, disfigure, hurt, injure, take its toll...'. A connotation is subjective, not a nuance that is necessarily picked up by everyone: it is a nuance that some readers etc perceive. And the fact that the Collins compilers stress the 'adverse' aspect means it is a connotation. That _doesn't_ mean it may not be used as a straight synonym for 'cause

Comment: I took your last comment as a prompt to avoid making unsupported contentions, even in comment. And I would agree. Sometimes I get, how should I say this ... immoderate. I don't think you're wrong. I'm sure just as many dictionaries disagree with my contention as agree. Yes, in many ways connotations, like beauty ...

Comment: ... change'. Indeed, context is a far more telling factor in judging positive or negative influence. But an uncontextualised 'It affected their performance' would rarely be taken as meaning that there was an improvement. Josh61 says 'My personal impression is that 'affect' is generally used to convey a negative influence ...'; he's picking up on a negative connotation (so there is one). As does Raghuraman R in his answer. It's even possible some people might pick up on a positive connotation, but nobody and no dictionary has mentioned this.

Comment: Psychologists/psychiatrists use "positive affect" quite often.

Comment: We're really ...aah ...discussing what 'connote' means here. I'd use 'affect' quite happily for +ve, neutral or -ve influences. _Connotation refers to the wide array of positive and negative associations that
most words naturally carry with them, whereas denotation is the precise, literal definition
of a word that might be found in a dictionary._ [[Banforth](http://www.csun.edu/~bashforth/098_PDF/06Sep15Connotation_Denotation.pdf)] And OP didn't define how he's using 'imply': demand or suggest. //  Glad to see you've included some decent references!

Comment: Well, they're not Collins, of course. :-)